# Agora localstream stopped but Video Icon still showing in the browser URL tab

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have an Agora localStream initiated with `AgoraRTC.createStream(defaultConfig)` which returns a `Stream` object. I started the localStream by calling `localStream.play()` and stopping it with `localStream.stop()`. When I call `localStream.stop()`, the stream is stopped and it gets removed. I also call `localStream.close()` to reset camera and microphone authorizations. But I still see the Video Icon visible in my Chrome Address bar stating that the page is using Audio, Video actively while technically that shouldn't be visible when the stream is closed. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Was this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by individually closing local video & audio tracks.

I referred to [this](https://docs.agora.io/en/help/integration-issues/web_camera_light).

So, basically, unless you close both video and audio tracks, the icon on the tab won't disappear; furthermore, to ensure that video state is reset, you need to at least close your video client.

```
localVideoTrack.close()
localAudioTrack.close()
```